# yoga/yoga.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode13

Same problem as in yoga/yoga.h file not found, I have read all the answers I have found but they did not help.

I am using Xcode 13.1, react-native 0.64.0, and getting this error when I try to build.

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: were you able to fix this error? If so, how??

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how I solved it exactly after a few tries it started to work.
first of all what is the version of xcode and react?

Comment: Actually, the project was built using react native version 0.59.x. I tried to update it but there was way too much work and I planned to go as it is and then encounter the issue. I have XCode 13.4.1 installed on my system.